# Querying Graphs with Gremlin

Tags: javascript, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop

Please help me with the query on Gremlin lang

I have a graph with 2 types of vertices: User and Group.
I need to find friends of 'U1'. If users have edges ( member or invite ) to 'Group A' need to flag them like the below result.

[image: [Graph image](https://ibb.co/D9VPKw4)]

Expected result : [ { U2: 'Member'}, { U3: 'Invited' }, { U4: 'Member'} ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from the vertex of U1 and from there you can go to all his friends using `out` step, then filter them with `where` step.

```
g.V().hasLabel('U1').out('Friend').
  where(out('Member', 'Invited').
    hasLabel('Group A'))
```

example: https://gremlify.com/1o0chgjomi6/1

**EDIT**

for this type of result you can do:

```
g.V().hasLabel('U1').out('Friend').
    as('friend').
  outE('Member', 'Invited').where(inV().
    hasLabel('Group A')).
  group().
    by(select('friend').label()).
    by(label())
```

example: https://gremlify.com/4qnd7wi1rnv

Comment: [Image](https://ibb.co/chQgG5L) Can I  get all friends like this. is it possible?  {
"U2":"Member",
"U3":"Invited", "U4": ""
}

Answer (score 0):

```
g.V().has('User', 'name', 'U1')
  .out('friend')
  .as('friends')
  .bothE('invited', 'member', 'friend')
  .where(or(inV().has('Group', 'name', 'G1'), outV().has('User', 'name', 'U1')))
  .group()
  .by(select('friends').values('name'))
  .by(label().fold())
```